# String pattern matching in function definition

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, downvalues

I have a function f and its downvalues. I want to code an extra downvalue for arguments of the form "part1:part2"

I don't understand why

```
f[a__~~":"~~b__] := {a,b}
```

does not work. I can only think of

```
f[string_String] /; StringMatchQ[string,__~~":"~~__] := StringCases[string, a__~~":"~~b__ :> {a,b}][[1]]
```

but this doesn't seem very smart as the string structure is examined two times.

Comment: `a__~~":"~~b__` is a `StringExpression`, not a `Pattern`. Try `Head[a__ ~~ ":" ~~ b__]` vs `Head[a_]`

Comment: Thanks, this explains my mistake

Comment: Equivalent to the second: `f[s_?(StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ ":" ~~ __] &)] := StringSplit[s, ":"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because it's simply not correct syntax.  String patterns and expression patterns are not interchangeable.  Each works only with its own set of functions: string patterns work only in `StringMatchQ` and expression patterns only work in `MatchQ`.

In function definitions you can only use expression patterns.

You can use something like this instead:

```
f[string_String] := 
 Module[{r}, r = StringCases[string, a__ ~~ ":" ~~ b__ :> {a, b}]; First[r] /; r =!= {}]
```

This special use of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) inside [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) makes it possible not to process the string twice yet still have a condition attached to the definition.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I thought (hoped?) that you could throw anything into function definition

Comment: @user2397318 Yes, you can use anything.  Your definition is valid, it just doesn't have the meaning you expected.  It will match `f[x ~~ ":" ~~ y]`, which as acl said is the same as `f[StringExpression[x, ":", y]]`.